# .htaccess Authorization header missing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

Can you tell what's wrong with this script ? Need to add Authorization header, but it does not.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In production enviroment, this script may will not work, because `public/` is not presented in the url.

Comment: I'm want to make laravel work on shared hosting, as index.php and other files located at public/ folder we need to make some changes. Everything works fine, except can't access Authorization header from php

Comment: You can also use **Setenvif authorization ^(.+)$ auth_head=$1** in htaccess to set enviornment var of authorization header. and then **print getenv("auth_head")** to print the value in php

Comment: @Starkeen good job, it did the trick, great thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Starkeen's comment, this trick works:

```
Setenvif authorization ^(.+)$ auth_head=$1
```

in htaccess to set enviornment var of authorization header. and then

```
print getenv("auth_head")
```

to print the value in php